# Annotation Scaling

Tags: annotation, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I made a map with annotations in QGIS 3.0.

This is how it looks like in the layout view:

[image: Map with Annotations in Layout View]

If I print the map as PDF, one would expect to get the PDF to be WYSIWYG, right? However, it looks like this (it's about half the size):

[image: Map with Annotations when printed]

Is there a way to influence the the scaling of the Annoations? I already tried to play with the Scale and Magnifier in the map view. I also tried to change the Scale in the map item.

The strange thing is, I believe it worked a few days ago. But today I installed QGIS 3.0 on a new PC and it showed the same behaviour...

Comment: Samen problem here, but much worse. Mine scales down to 10% or more of. I've tried it on QGis 3.6.........same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug, you should submit a [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis).

A possible workaround could be to change the **rendering** settings of the map from the `Item Properties` section. For a fairly simple map such as the one you have shown, you could try `Darken` mode. You will be prompted if you want to export the pdf as raster or vector.

---

I used a simple example, not sure if the same method can work with higher quality maps:

- Layout options

  [image: Layout]
- PDF output

  [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Joseph!

Changing the rendering settings of the map in the `Item Properties` section to `Darken`  did the trick for my simple example. However, for my more complex map, it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I was able to work around it by **increasing the font size to 20 point**. Increase the size of the annotation window to accommodate the enlarged text.

In the PDF export, the 20 pt font appears to be about 8-10 pt font. It's a bit blurry, so it's just barely readable. Choosing a chunky or bold style of font would probably help.

[image]

Note that you must [highlight the text in order to change the font size in a text annotation](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15415). Clearly this feature still has a few kinks to work out.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering settings (multiply or darken) suggested by @Joseph worked for some of my simple maps, but I still had trouble with more complex maps that had transparency settings on layers. I was able to adjust the font size of the annotation to get what I needed in a PDF.

Another workaround I found was to change the output resolution to 100 dpi when exporting (I usually use 300 dpi). There was a definite loss of quality on the resulting PDF, but the annotations were close to normal size.

FYI - it looks like the bug report is still open: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18373. I tried upgrading from 3.2.2 to 3.4.4 on Windows 7 with no improvement on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in 3.4.4 with annotation scaling and position. What Nate Wanner suggested, a lower 100 dpi does work. For me, 150 dpi does the job with adjusting the position of text/form annotations in main screen placement. I have about 8 layers in use.

Rendering in "Darken" mode made no difference for me; nor did exporting image as raster or vector.

Seems it's a matter of tweaking main screen placement and dpi setting until a bug fix evolves. From another novice, hope this helps others as well.